# Любимая бНОПНЯ! Или русския язык в программировании.

Tags: кодировка

Всех с Новым Годом!
А точнее - **я мНБШЛ цНДНЛ**! (тоже **бНОПНЯ**)
Писал-писал сайт много лет на windows-1251 (html, JS, CSS), тут решил подключить модулёк к нему на php (раньше хостинг не позволял с php и mySQL баловаться.)
Так вот, подключил значит, написал кодировку ему "charset=windows-1251".
Из БД там берётся пока что лишь одна циферка.
Другие проекты изначально делал на UTF-8, а этот весь на windows-1251.
• Почему так происходит, ведь PHP на 1251 и сайт тоже на 1251?
[> пример тут <](http://kansk-land.ru/soft/download.php)
Почему ни как не могут придти к стандарту по кириллице!
Эти свистопляски с кодировками, уже отчасти поднадоели.
——————————————
Или переписывать (делать перекодировку) всего прожекта под UTF-8?

Comment: Наверно все таки проще уже перевести на utf и забыть про эту проблему, чем она еще  раз будет всплывать.

Comment: Где смотреть конкретно проблемы с кодировкой? Я только потерянные изображения вижу.

Comment: @Etki - изображения для юзеров, зрить нужно в корень. т.е. в код.
Или вы сначала делаете дизайн, а под него код?

Comment: > зрить нужно в корень. т.е. в код

локализация проблемы: 5/5

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле, то, что вы изначально решили использовать кодировку НЕ UTF-8 - сугубо ваша проблема, ибо сложно поверить, что вы начинали "писать-писать" тот самый сайт в прошлом тысячелетии..

---

По поводу:

```
Почему ни_как не могут придти к стандарту по кириллице_?
Эти свистопляски с кодировками_ уже отчасти поднадоели.
```

Нельзя вот так просто взять и забыть о прошлом. Множество устройств и даже людей вроде вас все еще используют и будут использовать в обозримом будущем то, что даже сейчас можно считать устаревшим. Обратная совместимость, как-никак, дело очень нужное и серьёзное.

Ярким примером является, например, широкое использование языков низкого уровня( типа C и даже С++ ). Право, многие полагают, что в эпоху виртуализации( JVM & .NET в частности ) от использования более низкого уровня в процессе разработке нет никакого смысла. Однако же, если подумать, без C/C++ современный мир долго не продержится: в конце концов, не переписывать же исходники марсоходов и луноходов с нуля?

Answer (score -4):

Никого не надо слушать!
И не читать "умные" статьи про  "[Cannot modify header information - headers already sent](http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru/)"

Надо просто кодировку передавать прежде кода и даже ПРЕЖДЕ(!) php-кода(?).
Проблема решена, php код ставим только(!) после передачи кодировки в html и браузеру!
—
P.S. Дурацкое, "интерпретаторное" программирование!

Comment: > Ни кого не надо слушать!

Н**ик**ого. И надо.

> И не читать "умные" статьи

Там реально толково все расписано.

> Надо просто кодировку передавать прежде всего кода, и даже ПРЕЖДЕ(!) php-кода.

Эм. Если имеется в виду на стороне сервера (apache/nginx) - то это неправильно, приложение должно по-минимуму озадачивать сервер и по-максимуму брать задачи на себя.

> Проблема решена, php код ставим только(!) после передачи кодировки в html браузеру!

Это как? За вывод html отвечает php

Comment: > Дурацкое, интерпретаторное программирование!

1. Запятая не нужна
2. Сдается мне, вы все-таки не разобрались в вопросе

Кстати говоря, вот эти три символа вверху страницы:

> п»ї

Это и есть BOM (byte order mark), про который написано в той статье. С этим, кстати, связаны целых две забавных штуки: а) PHP на черт знает какому годе существования так и не умеет банально читать файлы и б) BOM для UTF-8 вообще не нужен, потому что в UTF-8 не существует деления на big и little endian (какой именно вариант применяется - я не помню, но он всегда один и тот же).

Comment: @Etki, BOM если там и был, то это от других подключённых php. В том его не было.  
И BOM я всегда выпиливаю сразу, это для меня как маленький паразит (если он залазит на сайт).  
---  
А кодировку (русския язык в американской ОС) не люблю, ещё со времён DOS'а. И коротких имён файлов.  
Проблема кодировки наверное будет всегда!  
Была в DOS'е, была в Delphi, была и есть в PHP, mySQL и т.д.